# What to do with not used DAC outputs?

Tags: dac

I want to use [this](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/256/MAX5102-1515830.pdf) DAC. It has two outputs. I only need one. Should I let the other one float or put it on ground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave it floating with no attached trace because it is a driven output. Don't leave a long trace connected as this trace could radiate/conduct switching noise out into your circuit.

If you *do* tie it to any other potential (e.g. GND) use a large resistor (e.g. 100K) in series to limit current.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you want to use one of the two DACs then you have to have shut-down tied to ground. This automatically means that both output amplifiers are active.

> *Should I let the other one float or put it on ground?*

If you connect an output to ground you might cause excessive current to be taken; it's an output after all so, leave it to do whatever it wants to do. Add a test point to the unused output in case you want to use it some time later but, don't connect it to ground.

Comment: @Yoomo, If you have the board space, a test point is a very good plan and some free insurance. A second channel could be very useful during development/testing.